# Bootstrap multiselect not working with knockout binding

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using [this plugin](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/) for implementing a multi-select dropdown with checkboxes using KnockoutJs in an ASP.NET MVC web application. I have followed the code in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joeheyming/q6gemrv5/), but the drop-down is not working whereas the fiddle works fine.

**HTML Code:**

```
<select id="status-select" multiple="multiple" class="form-control"
data-bind="options: $root.statuses, selectedOptions: $root.selectedStatuses, multiselect: { includeSelectAllOption: true }">
</select>
...
...
@section require {
    require(['app/viewModel']);
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#status-select").multiselect();
    });
</script>
```

**viewModel.ts:**

```
export class ViewModel {
    statusOptions = [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
    ];
    statuses = ko.observableArray(this.statusOptions);
    selectedStatuses = ko.observableArray([]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The following is the order in which I have included scripts in my project:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
```

The following is the output I get:

[image]

Please note that the options inside the `select` tag are bound correctly, but nothing displays in the drop-down since the `ul` tag is empty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? Let me know if I could further help you with it.

Comment: @HeyJude I couldn't get it to work. So I had to ditch the plugin and implement one from scratch using bootstrap drop-down. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're using Bootstrap 4, while bootstrap-multiselect officialy only works with Bootstrap 3.

That said, there's an open issue on Github named [Bootstrap 4 compatibility](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1015) which requests an official support for Bootstrap 4, and a user named @adeeb1 suggests its own implementation, which works - [see it live here](https://jsfiddle.net/xdqn8oew/).

Few notes:

- The non-official support for Bootstrap 4 is not perfect, though: in my demo, you can see that the "Select all" checkbox is not aligned with the other checkboxes.
- My demo uses `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`, (note the use of `bundle`), which includes `popper.js`. Your snippet doesn't uses the `bundle` version, so either change it, or include a standalone version of `popper.js`.
- Your `statusOptions` property is not an `observableArray`, and therefore won't utilize two-way binding. I changed it in my demo.
- No need to use `$("#status-select").multiselect()`, knockout does it for you.

Comment: I have tried this. Knockout does not create the multi-select by itself. I have to use `$("#status-select").multiselect()` for the multi-select dropdown to be created. Even if I do that, I am not getting any values inside `selectedOptions` when I select something. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I have done the `options` and `selectedOptions` bindings using observables. I have a standalone version of `popperjs` included. Can `popperjs` be the reason for the drop-down to not work?

Comment: You can see that my demo doesn't use `$("#status-select").multiselect()`, so you too probably don't need it, and the reason it still doesn't work for you is something else. Press F12 to see if there are any errors in the console.

Comment: There were no errors in the console. If I don't use `$("#status-select").multiselect()`, the result is an ordinary multi-select drop-down where I have to use shift key to select multiple items.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing a live demo of your code. can you make a jsfiddle? If not, I suggest you take my live demo and run it locally, then compare it to your code and see what's the difference.